# git rm -f applied recursively without `-r` specified

Tags: git

I moved some files around after adding/staging them. File structure looked like:

```
parent/dir1/script0.py
parent/dir1/script1.py
parent/script0_delete_me.py
parent/script1_delete_me.py
```

While inside `dir1` I ran `git rm -f ../*.py` (note, I did not specify `-r`). I was expecting the outcome to be:

```
parent/dir1/script0.py
parent/dir1/script1.py
parent/
parent/
```

but instead it was:

```
parent/dir1/
parent/dir1/
parent/
parent/
```

I have no problem getting the files back that I need. But why did `git rm -f ../*.py` search recursively even though `-r` was never given? A quick skim of the docs for `git rm -f` indicate that a recursive search requires the `-r` option.

Regular bash does not behave like this:

```
~/test/dir1$ ls ../
dir1  d.py
~/test/dir1$ rm -f ../*.py
~/test/dir1$ ls
d.py
```

EDIT: To reproduce:

```
~$ git init t
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/t/.git/
~$ cd t
~/t$ touch d.py
~/t$ git add d.py
~/t$ git commit -m "init"
[master (root-commit) f59e049] init
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 d.py
~/t$ mkdir u
~/t$ git mv d.py u/d.py
~/t$ cd u
~/t/u$ ls
d.py
~/t/u$ ls ../
u
~/t/u$ git rm -f ../*.py
rm 'u/d.py'
~/t/u$ ls
~/t/u$
```

I think probably I wasn't viewing this correctly / was trying to do something the wrong way. But still this behavior seems weird.

Comment: Were there any non-Python files in the deleted directories?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. E.g. README.md is still intact.

Comment: Is the README file (or any other non-python file) inside the `parent` or `dir1` directory? For git, deleting all files in a directory is equivalent to deleting the directory.

Comment: `README.md` is in `dir1`

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this. Can you add the commands needed to bring the repo to what it was immediately before you ran `git rm -f ../*.py` in step 1 (preferably every command needed to run starting with a `git init`).

Comment: @amphetamachine see updated question with example to reproduce.

Comment: @dan1st any more ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's command-line pathspecs have their quirks, and shell globbing also has its quirks. The interaction bit you.

The short form is, you want to either `git rm -f ':(glob)../*.py'` or run with either `nullglob` or `failglob` set in your scripts or shell startup (probably `~/.bashrc`) to avoid this, uhh, perhaps overeager, catering for entering ambiguous command arguments without having to warn the shell off explicitly.

Git command-line pathspecs do not treat directory separators specially, shell globs do, and many shells will pass an unmatched glob along to the command untouched, in case it wasn't really a filename and the command will make sense of the string some other way.

So since there were no paths ending `.py` in the parent directory, Git saw `rm` `-f` and `*.py` as args, and Git's `rm` interpreted that as a Git pathspec.

The pain/gain ratio on changing any of this behavior, in shells or in Git, is intolerable. Say `git help glossary` and hunt up `pathspec` to see all the many sometimes-very-handy things you can do with it.

Stare at this suspiciously then try it:

```bash
sh -x <<\EOD; rm -rf test
git init test; cd $_
mkdir inner; cd $_; touch a.file; git add .
ls ../*.file
git ls-files ../*.file
shopt -s failglob
ls ../*.file
git ls-files ../*.file
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s nullglob
ls ../*.file
git ls-files ../*.file
git ls-files ':(glob)../*.file'
EOD
```

There are several more quirks at play here, it's just how it works, and each choice caters to specific bits of workflow that some people hit *a lot* and others, pretty much never.